# Passing an include file from a function in a function

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to classes and struggling to connect a simple function to another function. Whenever I add an echo 'test' inside the ConnectDB function it passes through the 'test'. However, it doesn't include the include files.

It's probably a noob mistake.

Note: When I copy/paste the content from ConnectDB to the UpdateFollowers function it works. I'm looking for a way to save time without using an include file.

```
class UpdateAccountInfo {


public function ConnectDB() {

        if (strposa($_SESSION['geturl'], $_SESSION['folders']) != FALSE) {
            include '../_includes/config.php';
            include '../_includes/opendb.php';
        } else {
            include './_includes/config.php';
            include './_includes/opendb.php';
        }   


}

// update followers
public function UpdateFollowers($getid) {

        $this->ConnectDB();

        //find the source of the ig account 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ig_accounts WHERE iid = $getid";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $igname = $row["igname"];
        }
............
```

Comment: Isn't it `strpos`??. You should be getting an undefined function right? And it should be  `!== FALSE`

Comment: I assume you are trying to get database connection. If so,  just have a construct function and initialize the database connection there.

Comment: problem is in `variable scope` becase variable `$conn` which you initialize in inluded file is accessible only inside of method `ConnectDB` therefore not available in method `UpdateFollowers` take a look at this nice post about variable scope: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577/7028432

Comment: @Akintunde strposa is a custom function I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What is a class?

Before going into any explanation concerning the case at hand, I think it's important to get some OOP concepts straight first. From the example in the question, I get the feeling that your understanding of classes is that they simply are "function buckets" so to speak. This isn't the case. A [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) is a generic data structure you can use to define objects, behavior related to those objects and data used by those objects.

```
class Human {

    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $dateOfBirth;

    public function __construct($fn, $ln, $dob) {
        $this->firstName = $fn;
        $this->lastName = $ln;
        $this->dateOfBirth = $dob;
    }

    public function getFullName() {
        return $this->firstName.' '.$this->lastName;
    }
}
```

In the example above, we've defined a basic structure shared by all objects of type `Human` as well as [encapsulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)#General_definition) some very basic functionalities (getting the full name of our `Human`).

If we take a look at your example, `UpdateAccountInfo` is more of  a *functionality* rather than an *object*. It is a process that will always be performed by some other component of the system, for the purpose of this example let's call that other component an `Account`.

```
class Account {

    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $conn;  // <-- our DB connection
    /* other Account properties */

    public function __construct($id, $name) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        /* Initialize DB connection */
    }

    public function updateFollowers() {
        /* Perform any logic required to update the followers */
    }
}
```

Now we have an object of type `Account` to which we add however many functions we need in the future. `addFollowers()`, `removeFollowers()`, `changeUsername()`. Those are all examples of processes that belong to the `Account` object and will likely never be used by any other component of the system.

### Initializing the Database connection

You may have noticed that I have left out the database initialization part out of the previous example. There is a few reasons for this but mainly:

1. Opening and closing a connection each time create an instance of `Account` (or any object for that matter) using the `new` keyword is very costly.
2. It breaks the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). I won't get into that too much as it is a pretty lengthy topic. What you need to know for the time being is that it essentially means that an object should only deal with its own data/processes, and no more. In this case, opening a database connection simply isn't the job of `Account`.

To get around this, we can simply encapsulate the database connection logic in a `Database` object.

```
class Database {

    private $connection;

    public function connect($localhost, $name, $password, $database) {
        $this->connection = new mysqli($localhost, $name, $password, $database);
        if($this->connection->connect_error) {
            /* throw an exception */
        }
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

Now you simply need to initialize the database connection once at the beginning of the script, and pass it around to other objects/functions that may need it.

```
<?php
    include_once('../../config.php');
    /* include any other required files */
    $database = new Database($config['localhost'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);

    // get a specific account
    $account = new Account(/* ... */, $database);

    // update the account's followers
    $account->updateFollowers(/* ... */);
```

If we want to modify a second account, we can do so using the same database connection we just opened.

```
<?php
    /* ... code from previous example ... */
    // initialize a new Account with the same Database
    $otherAccount = new Account(/* new account's info */, $database);
    $otherAccount->updateFollowers(/* ... */);
```

---

### Further readings

1. [PHP documentation on OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)
2. Wikipedia page on [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
3. [How to initialize a database connection](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17)